# Finding maximum numbers in array with pointers and taking their positions to another array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm doing a project now with C language and i have a problem in one part on project.Basically im trying to find maximum M numbers in my main array and i'm taking their ID numbers to another array.The ID numbers of the these max numbers are their position in array.

My main array is tresh_arr and  have N numbers,the numbers are double.

My code block which doesn't work is :

```
    double max=0;
    int *max_arr;
    int k,tmp,flag=0;
    max_arr=calloc(M,sizeof(int));



for(i=0;i<M;i++)  //I will find maximum M numbers
{
    for(j=0;j<N;j++) //There is a N numbers in my array
    {
        if( *(tresh_arr+j) > max   ) //I'm trying to take the Id numbers to the tresh_arr
            {
                flag=0;
                for(k=0;k<i+1;k++) 
                {
                    if( *(max_arr+k)==j )
                    {   
                       flag=0;
                       break;
                    }
                    else 
                        flag=1; 
                }

                if(flag==1)
                {
                    max = *(tresh_arr+j);
                    tmp=j;
                }                               
            }
    }
    *(max_arr+i)=tmp;
}`
```

But my code doesn't work and just finding maximum number and writing M times the  Id of this maximum number.What should i do? Thank you and sorry for my faults if have.

Comment: Debugger.................

Comment: What if you sort the array and take the M maximum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are mistakes in your program:

1) In second last line you should do 
             *(max_arr+i)=max;  // not tmp

2)Inside each forloop over i set max to least number

```
for(i=0;i<M;i++)  //I will find maximum M numbers
```

{

```
 max =-1;    //**********YOU MISSED THIS*****************

for(j=0;j<N;j++) //There is a N numbers in my array
{
```

3) Above break you should set flag to 1 and no need to set it to 0 again and in if you should check for flag==0 which basically means element was not found

```
            for(k=0;k<i;k++) 
            {
                if( *(max_arr+k)==tresh_arr[j] )
                {  
                   flag=1;
                   break;
                }
            }

            if(flag==0)
            {
                max = *(tresh_arr+j);
                tmp=j;
            }
```

Also its good to write *(A+j) as A[j] in C, they both are exactly same, earlier one is sort of too verbose

Comment: *(max_arr+i)=tmp because i'm taking the position of maximum number not it's self.and i tried to change my code as you shown but it still doesn't work.Also thanks for write suggestion.

Comment: Then  change this comparison
      if( *(max_arr+k)==tresh_arr[j] )    // tresh_arr[j] by j

Comment: https://gist.github.com/coderabhishek/42bb47c5b4cbb29afd7d62f0dc78e89e

See here , your code working

Comment: im trying to take their positions to max_arr for your example max_arr=[8,7,6,5,4] should be result because max 5 number is 9,8,7,6,5  and 8,7,6,5,4 are their positions in array

Comment: I wrote for actual element but you can change that simply, otherwise its working fine(prints elements 9,8,7,6,5)
 just see the changes I have made to flow of code

Comment: okay it is working now thank you so much i appreciate it.